# Why I can not send messages with telethon, An Invalid Peer was used

Tags: telethon

I'm trying to send some messages with telethon client API, I have scraped users from groups and have them all in a .csv.

It works well with my API credentials, although, I'm getting an error when using a different account with different API credentials
`[!] Error: An invalid Peer was used. Make sure to pass the right peer type and that the value is valid (for instance, bots cannot start conversations) (caused by SendMessageRequest)`

Here is the code https://gist.github.com/Raduc4/fd62662cd602db60ca4311af3608a6b2

Personal opinion: I think there is an error because I have scraped with an account and trying to send with a different one.

Comment: yes. access_hash is account unique. the scraper has to also be the sender.

Comment: Thank you, how can I do to send it from different accounts?

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before using unrelated tags ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the session  is already started
Maybe you did not kill the previous process